# ExtJS - grid empty but store loaded

Tags: ajax, extjs, model, store

My grid is not filled, though the store is filled with json data. What is wrong?
I want all data from `"csv":[...]` to be written to the grid columns.
If I `console.log()` the store, my json data is located at `store.proxy.reader.[jsonData|rawData].data.csv` => Array[4]

Json Data:

```
{"status":{"status":0,"msg":"Ok","protocolversion":"1.1.json"},"data":{"headline":{"headline":"headline"},"csv":[{"key":"0","value":"...lugin\/monitor\/files\/logfilefilter_worker_error.log"},{"key":"1","value":"...les\/logfilefilter-worker01-progress.log.1331769600"},{"key":"2","value":"...\/application\/x\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/Test.log"},{"key":"3","value":"...ind\/plugin\/monitor\/files\/logfile_for_navi_test.log"}]}}
```

Model:

```
Ext.define( 'Monitor.model.ComboLogfiles', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [ {name: 'key'}, {name: 'value'} ] 
 } );
```

Store:

```
Ext.define( 'Monitor.store.ComboLogfiles', {
  extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
  model   : 'Monitor.model.ComboLogfiles',
  proxy   : {
     type       : 'ajax',
     url        : '/devel/phi/dev/04-presentation/http-api/index.php',
     extraParams: {
        user      : 'test',
        pass      : 'test',
        vers      : '1.1.json',
        module    : 'monitor',
        func      : 'getLogfiles'
     },
     reader     : {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'csv'
        // root: 'data'
     }

  },
  autoLoad: true
} );
```

Controller

```
var store = Ext.create('Monitor.store.ComboLogfiles');

oLogfileSelector = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
        title: 'Logfiles',
        width: '200',
        height: '400',
        autoScroll: true,
        flex: 1,
        minimizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        style: 'background-color: #fff;',
        items: [{
              xtype: 'panel',
              items: [
                 Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                    id: 'mygrid',
                    store: store,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    title: 'Logfiles',
                    columns: [
                       {
                             text: 'Key',
                             width: 50,
                             sortable: false,
                             dataIndex: 'key'
                       }
                       ,{
                             text: 'File',
                             width: 100,
                             sortable: false,
                             dataIndex: 'value'
                       }
                    ]
                 })
              ]

        }]

     }).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try like this:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'data.csv',
    successProperty:false
}
```